# Interpretation of the graph of excitation current for magnetic circuit

Tags: magnetics, hysteresis

[image]

(From Electric Machinery, Fitzgerald)

Why does the current waveform here have such a sharp peak like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the current waveform here have such a sharp peak like that?

Because the magnetic core is saturating. If the core wasn't saturating, the current into the device would be a sinewave (assuming the voltage supplied is a sinewave). Here's another example: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/AC/AC_9.html). And below is a gif of how this happens due to the core saturation characteristic: -

[image]

[GIF source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Power_Transformer_Over-Excitation.gif).

Comment: I love the illustrations you find!

Comment: @Neil_UK I draw them all myself hehe.

Comment: Note that the OP cropped the hysteresis loop out of the posted figure. The explanation is in the book, but not so dynamically presented.

Comment: @Andyaka This makes things so much clearer, thank you! There was an explanation in the book, but nothing can beat your animation! I had to crop the picture out since stackexchange wouldn't let me post a pic of that size.

Comment: It’s not really my animation. I found on the link underneath.